# I am having difficulties in retrieving json after ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi i am a beginner in retrieving json after ajax post. i post json data to php and want to retrieve json and display in html console.. 
i encounterd a problem.. the problem states

```
"Status Code: 200

ErrorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

jqXHR.responseText:

C:\wamp\www\AbdWeb\AJAX6\jsonpass.php:3:
array (size=1)
  '{"PostCountry":"singapore","PostTime":"141253"}' => string '' (length=0)"
```

---

i want to view the data in the json format.... How to solve this error....

My code is found below..
in html file

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> POST JSON DATA VIA AJAX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-
1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Show JSON DATA</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form>
    <input type="hidden" id="country" value="singapore" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" id="time" value="141253" readonly>
    <input type="button" value="submit me" onclick="showData();">
    </form>

    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="resulte"></div>
    <h3>Look at the console. Click Ctrl + Shift + J to VIEW THE CONSOLE 
PAGE.
    </h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var country = document.getElementById("country");
        var time = document.getElementById("time");
        var postData = {
            PostCountry: country.value,
            PostTime: time.value
        };
        function showData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType:  "JSON",
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                url: "jsonpass.php",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
            },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or 
Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!");
                    $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p>
<p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p>
<div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown:');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                },
            });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in php file

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

my code is about performing ajax post json data to php script and view the data in the html console.. but i enocuntered error and i have no idea on how to do this..
my question is how to retrieve json data and show in the json format..... using two variables country and time....... please fix the error. please help me...

Comment: just `echo json_encode($_POST);` instead of `echo var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the `json` data so it should be like this

`echo var_dump($_POST);`

To

`echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: oh that is how is it... thank you so much. i am struggling so much

Comment: Glad it help you :) Don't forgot to appreciate the answer .  take a tour  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Problem is a returned object its a not a valid JSON [here](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e483cbda076f21579bfeea68f2147909) you will see exception of your JSON object... You need return correct JSON object from your PHP code for solving problem. [Here you can find how need return JSON object PHP](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/)